# How to add hash to the generated css file when using rollup and roll-plugin-postcss

Tags: rollup, postcss, css-modules

I'm using rollup to bundle the code. 
For bundling the css I'm using rollup-plugin-postcss. I'm not able to figure out how to add hash to the generated css file.
Here is my postCss config:

```
        postcss({
            plugins: [autoprefixer()],
            sourceMap: !isProd,
            extract: `${BUILD_DIR}/styles/index.css`,
            modules: true,
            minimize: isProd,
            use: ['sass'],
            extensions: ['.scss'],
            inject: false,
            autoModules: false,
        }),
```

With this config I'm able to generate `index.css` in the build directory but I want to generate `index-[hash_string].css`

Comment: Looks like this is not supported out of the box, although there is an open PR to add the feature: https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss/pull/226

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you're ok with using the same name for both your JS and CSS bundles.

The gist is that your JS bundle can be automatically named with a hash, and your CSS bundle can automatically get the same name:

- JS: use [`entryFileNames`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputentryfilenames) which supports a `[hash]` placeholder.
- CSS: if you do not specify a custom filename in the `extract` option, it will "[extract CSS to the same location where JS file is generated but with `.css` extension](https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-postcss#extract)".

```js
output: {
  // ...
  dir: `${BUILD_DIR}/styles`,
  entryFileNames: "[name].[hash].js",
},
plugins: [
  postcss({
    extract: true
    // ...
  }),
],
```